# Dictionary with Tuples as Values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a location name and then a latitude and longitude for each location. I'm trying to determine the best way to express a single key with two values in Python. I was thinking this:

```
dict = {
    'California': ('36.46715833333333', '-117.85891388888888'),
    'California2': ('36.46715833333333', '-117.85891388888888'),
}
```

Then to add more:

```
dict['California'] = ('36.46715833333333', '-117.85891388888888')
```

But then how would I easily iterate through each and extract them?

```
for location in dict:
    for lat, lon in location:
        print lat, lon
```

This gives a ValueError stating it does not have more than one value to unpack. How do I iterate through this and get each lat and long?

Comment: Please see the docs on `dict`; look for `dict.iteritems()` or `dict.items()`, or `dict.values()` or `dict.itervalues()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterating over a dict object iterates over its keys. You have to either get the value explicitly:

```
for location in d:
    lat, long = d[location]
```

Or use `.items()`:

```
for name, location in d.items():
    lat, long = location
```

Or use tuple unpacking with that:

```
for name, (lat, long) in d.items():
    ...
```

Also, don't name your dictionary `dict`. You're shadowing the builtin `dict` (and `long`, but you probably won't notice).

Comment: +1 for lots of good advice. I'd stick with `lon` instead of `long`, though (as you mention; it's shadowing the builtin).

Answer (score 1):

As another answer stated, iterating a dict only gets the keys not the values. The most direct way to iterate the way you want:

```
for lat, lon in d.itervalues():
```

To get all three:

```
for location, (lat, lon) in d.iteritems():
```

Comment: Presumably the OP wants access to the keys as well, or he would have just used a list instead of the dictionary...

Comment: @HenryKeiter, the example and question only mentioned the coordinates - I assumed the keys were used in a different part of the application.

Comment: Yes, I need all three values.